Deploying Field History tracking for Activity object in Salesforce
So as we know the Activity object in Salesforce is pretty special as it contains two "children" Task and Event. You cannot create a field directly on the Task object. Rather you create the field on the Activity object and it becomes available on both Task and Event. So in the UI we have created a field on the Activity object. Now we want to track the history for this field. But the Activity object does not support field tracking in the UI. So you must go to the Task object where all Activity fields are available to be selected to be tracked. Everything works great so far. But when it comes the time to create a PR with these changes there is no line within the Activity.CUSTOMFIELD file to denote it as being tracked since Activity does not support field tracking, but Task does. So if we go to the Task objet within VScode and look at the fields there the custom field is not available because it technically exists only on the Activity object.
Long story short, how do we enable field history tracking on the Task object for the Activity custom field via metadata?

The answer appears to be, you can't do this. It's a manual deployment step for custom fields.
